# Best practice around parsing exception.toString() to perform some logic

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to determine the best way to handle exceptions based on what is contained in the toString() method of an exception since the exceptions I am handling are wrapped and rethrown.  For example I may have the following printed out when I print out exception.toString() to the console caused by a timeout:

`DependencyFailureException [origin=someClass::someMethod statusReason=timeout]`

In the stack trace further down there is a more specific serviceTimeoutException which is re-thrown wrapped in DependencyFailure.  That exception would be more appropriate to catch upstream but I don't have permission to edit that code to make sure it is not wrapped before being re thrown.

What would be a good way to extract `statusReason=timeout` out of the toString() to then perform some logic like emitting timeout metrics at that stage?  Is this even a good idea? I haven't really seen many examples of this.

Essentially in our code base, specific exceptions are caught early on and then re thrown as a generic failure exception with some specific context message appended to them.

Any insight into this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be printing `exception.toString()` and you definitely shouldn't be parsing it. "Is this even a good idea?" no, it's definitely not a good idea. "I haven't really seen many examples of this." that's because it's a bad idea.

Comment: Josh Bloch talks about this in *Effective Java*. He says that you should provide programmatic access to any information contained in a `toString()`, in order to avoid developers attempting to parse it (and then being broken when the format changes).

Comment: Best practice is "don't". The actual exception type may not be precise enough for you, but there is nothing else you can rely on.

Comment: What should I do then to perform some logic in case such an exception is thrown and its because of a timeout?

Comment: Get permission to change it, or ask those who won't let you what the plan is.

Comment: Thanks I will ask.  Also can I use getCause() and try it match that with an exceptionType I am looking for?

Comment: Sure, chase the `getCause()` chain, but you're only entitled to check the type, not the message.

Comment: The DependencyFailureException could provide methods to get the origin and statusReason.